# Is it possible to use multiple variables instead of selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know that it's faster to do the following:

```
var $header = $("#header");
$header.css({color:"#ff0000"});
$header.find("a").addClass("foo");
```

Instead of:

```
$("#header").css({color:"#ff0000"});
$("#header a").addClass("foo");
```

Because jQuery doesn't need to find the elements again in the DOM as we have direct reference to them.

Let's say that I have this:

```
var $header_elements = $("#header li");
var $footer_elements = $("#footer li");
```

And I use both individually for a few jQuery manipulations. But then, I need to do something on both. Using selector, I would do this:

```
$("#header li, #footer li").css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

But then, the DOM needs to be parsed again to find matching elements. Is there a way to use my previously declared variables instead of a new selector? Something like the following (which is **not** working, I know, it's to give an idea of what I'm looking for):

```
$($header_elements + $footer_elements).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

I think that the selector returns some kind of array or object. What I'm looking for is a way to merge those. Anyone know if this is possible and how to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$header_elements.add($footer_elements).css({color:'#ff0000'});
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .add()
>   method constructs a new jQuery object
>   from the union of those elements and
>   the ones passed into the method. The
>   argument to .add() can be pretty much
>   anything that $() accepts, including a
>   jQuery selector expression, references
>   to DOM elements, or an HTML snippet.

Comment: Or to use his source examples: `$header_elements.add($footer_elements).css({color:'#ff0000'});`

Comment: Maybe not the fastest possibility according to the tests I did, but gnarf is right, it looks cleaner and in case where there are duplicates between the two "sets", it'll take care of it. Thanks!

Comment: For this case, add() is the correct function to use. Almost unexpectedly, add() does not permanently modify the jQuery collection. So, even after you add $footer_elements to $header_elements, references to $header_elements from that point on will only effect the original collection. $.merge, however, will permanently modify the first collection in the argument, so after $.merge($header_elements,$footer_elements), any action taken on $header_elements will effect the $footer_elements collection as well. - Example here: http://jsbin.com/osupi3/2/edit

Answer (score 24):

Here is a solution:

```
$.merge($header_elements, $footer_elements).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

I tested it with JS Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/bgLfz/1/

I tested using selector each time, variable for both selector, variables with $.merge() and using .add(). Each test was run 1000 times.

Results on my side are as follow (from faster to slower):

1. Using $.merge() (average of 7ms)
2. Using both variable one after the other (average of 10ms but the code needs to be duplicated)
3. Using .add() (average of 16ms)
4. Using selectors each time (average of 295ms)

Comment: it will definitely be slower as jquery will have to merge the variables and then still go through them with `each`.

Comment: Merge will append directly to `$header_elements` though...  Making it contain `$footer_elements` as well

Comment: See http://jsperf.com/adding-selectors for some simple performance testing...  Also note, the function `add()` takes more time, but it also looks cleaner, and removes potential duplicates :)

Comment: @Raveren - Take a look at the jsperf - The "slowerness" is almost un-noticeable.

Comment: Performance isn't so much the issue here - the fact that $.merge() permanently modifies the first argument is a much larger concern( as gnarf pointed out). After the merge, $header_elements will now contain the $footer_elements collection, meaning if you just wanted to affect the header elements, you couldn't (without running the query again). Example is here: http://jsbin.com/osupi3/2/edit

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) or [`merge`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) method:
**Add**

```
$header_elements.add($footer_elements).css({color:'#f00'});
```

**merge**

```
$.merge($header_elements, $footer_elements).css({color:"#f00"});
```

Both work, but **add is more performant**.
[image]
**Source:** http://jsperf.com/add-vs-merge

**Credit:** I upvoted @GenericTypeTea and @Gabriel answers, did a summary of both, compared them and here is the result.

Comment: are there any caveats when there are more than two variables being added or merged together?  and what would the correct syntax be for such a scenario,  eg:  do you chain the `add()` methods like: `$my_var_1.add($my_var_2).add($my_var_3).add($my_var_4)` or does `add()` accept an array of variables like: `$my_var_1.add($my_var_2, $my_var_3, $my_var_4)`?

Answer (score 6):

Pass an array of references:

```
$([$header_elements, $footer_elements]).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

Comment: This would be my approach, but you can't pass jQuery objects in the array. You need to pass DOM elements. `$([$header_elements[0], $footer_elements[0]])`

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter performance wise wether you'll do something like (even if it worked):

```
$($header_elements + $footer_elements).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

or do them separately:

```
$($header_elements).css({color:"#ff0000"});
$($footer_elements).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

as jquery will internally go through the supplied arguments using `each()`.

If the principle is more `DRY` inspired, than performance wise, you can create a function:

```
function makeThemRed( el ) {el.css({color:"#ff0000"})}
```

and then

```
makeThemRed($header_elements);
makeThemRed($footer_elements);
```

or even:

```
function makeThemRed() 
{
   var l=arguments.length,
       o=0;
   while (o<l) {
       arguments[o++].css({color:"#ff0000"})
    }
}
```

and then

```
 makeThemRed($header_elements, $footer_elements); //any number of parameters
```

Answer (score 3):

The thing with using 'merge' is that it's limited to just two selectors, and using 'add' will be so messy if it's more than two, so if it's more than two, you should use 'each' like this:

```
$([selector1, selector2, selector3, .....etc]).each(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: If you are going to answer a question almost 4 years after it's been posted, you should be absolutely sure that you are actually answering the question correctly and that your solution is better than the already accepted one. Your answer is not even close to answering the original question.

Comment: I thought the " original question " is somehow related to jquery ;) :D

Answer (score 2):

To keep the code simple and **prevent code duplication** I used a `forEach` loop.

```js
var $header_items = $("#header li");
var $footer_items = $("#footer li");

[$header_items, $footer_items].forEach(function($blockItems){
    // do logic here
    $blockItems.css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always set all of the elements to one variable:

```
var $lis = $('#header li, #footer li');
$($lis).css({color:"#ff0000"});
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP said they **didn't** want to do.

Answer (score -2):

Use ES6 template literals for multiple variables as selectors:

```
$(`${$header_elements}, ${$footer_elements}`).css('color','#ff0000');
```

Comment: The variables are jQuery collections so you'll just get `"[object Object], [object Object]"`

Comment: In Gabriel's original question, they are neither arrays nor objects, but simple variables containing selectors.  In that context, it works fine.

Comment: No they're not. `var $header_elements = $("#header li");
var $footer_elements = $("#footer li");` <-- jQuery collections. And, you're missing the entire point of the question – *"Is there a way to use my previously declared variables instead of a new selector?"* and you're specifically creating a new selector.

Comment: If you want to answer an 8 years old question, please be sure that your answer is better than the accepted one.