# Trigger Click Event on Multiple Element in one line or at once

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following piece of code:

```
var entity = null;
var brand = null;

$('li.level1 > a[datanavigationnode="WF/001/DAM"]').each(function(){
  var thisEntity = $(this);
  var thisEntityParent = $(this).parent();

  var liLevel2 = $(thisEntityParent).find('li.level2');
  var brands = $('> a[datanavigationnode="WF/001/DAM/001"]', liLevel2);


  if(brands.length > 0) {
    entity = thisEntity;
    brand = $(brands[0]);

    return false;
  }                 
}); 


if(entity !== null && brand !== null) {
  var entityLi = $(entity).parent();
  var entityTypeLi = $(entityLi).parents('li.level0');

  var entityTypeHitArea = $('> div.hitarea', entityTypeLi);
  var entityHitArea = $('> div.hitarea', entityLi);

  $(entityTypeHitArea).click();
  $(entityHitArea).click();
  $(brand).click();
}
```

As you can see I am triggering three click events at the end. Is there any way to do it in one line? I have tried this: `(entityTypeHitArea, entityHitArea, brand).click();` but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried trigger("click")? => http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for: [Is it possible to use multiple variables instead of selectors in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576592/is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-variables-instead-of-selectors-in-jquery)

I can't comment on performance though.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Nicolas in the comment is correct. `$('#one').add('#two').add('#three').click();`

Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37gky4s7/

Comment: So basically the OP should try `$(entityTypeHitArea).add(entityHitArea).add(brand).click();` in that case?

Comment: Correct. Edited the post and included a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write it like this:

```
entityTypeHitArea.add(entityHitArea).add(brand).trigger("click");
```

Here is a simple [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x32rwujb/1/)..

Note: Don't make your code too complex just to avoid querying `"#id1,#id2"`, because `"#id1,#id2"` approach is faster than what you want..