# Using two variables as selectors to call a function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

Is it possible, after declaring two vars, to use them together to call a function in jQuery?

like:

```
var test1 = $('#mytest1');
var test2 = $('#mytest2');

test1,test1.fadeOut(100);
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use JSLint to help you to find common mistakes in scripts, If you try to do something like `var1, var2.method()`, it will say `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can just include the selectors within quotes to the `$` function:

```js
$('#mytest1, #mytest2').fadeOut(2000);
```

```css
#mytest1, #mytest2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytest1"></div>
<div id="mytest2"></div>
```

If you wish to use the existing variables you've already declared, you can use `.add()` as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3576622/4875631):

```js
var test1 = $('#mytest1');
var test2 = $('#mytest2');

$(test1).add(test2).fadeOut(2000);
```

```css
#mytest1, #mytest2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mytest1"></div>
<div id="mytest2"></div>
```

Comment: You should "normally hide" the first snippet and show the second...;) +1

Answer (score 2):

If you don't already have two variables, just select both.  Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#selecting-elements-with-a-comma-separated-list-of-selectors

```
$('#mytest1, #mytest2').fadeOut();
```

If you already have both in two separate variables, you can combine them.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/add/

```
test1.add(test2).fadeOut();
```

Comment: Whoops... You actually replied the same as me faster! I did not see. ;)

Comment: That's perhaps what I was looking for :) Thanks